# Import Configurable Product not link to associate simple product

Tags: magento, magmi

I read a lot of document about import configurable product, add column, change setting etc... but non of them work or i just doing it wrong. Configurable product not link to any associate product, also visible of associate prd in csv file is "Not Visible Individually" but after importing, they all change to "catalog, search".

Already turned on Configurable item process, bundle, grouped in magmi

[CSV sample [Spread sheet]](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AjV_5KKOd4Z4zSW1IPyIr6Ind3zEy3CL8EeuzSnJcU0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
    store;websites;attribute_set;type;category_ids;sku;has_options;name;meta_title;meta_description;image;small_image;thumbnail;gallery;url_key;url_path;custom_design;page_layout;options_container;country_of_manufacture;msrp_enabled;msrp_display_actual_price_type;gift_message_available;gift_wrapping_available;color;status;visibility;tax_class_id;occasion;apparel_type;sleeve_length;fit;size;length;gender;description;short_description;meta_keyword;custom_layout_update;special_from_date;special_to_date;news_from_date;news_to_date;custom_design_from;custom_design_to;price;special_price;weight;msrp;gift_wrapping_price;qty;min_qty;use_config_min_qty;is_qty_decimal;backorders;use_config_backorders;min_sale_qty;use_config_min_sale_qty;max_sale_qty;use_config_max_sale_qty;is_in_stock;low_stock_date;notify_stock_qty;use_config_notify_stock_qty;manage_stock;use_config_manage_stock;stock_status_changed_auto;use_config_qty_increments;qty_increments;use_config_enable_qty_inc;enable_qty_increments;is_decimal_divided;stock_status_changed_automatically;use_config_enable_qty_increments;product_name;store_id;product_type_id;product_status_changed;product_changed_websites;image_label;small_image_label;thumbnail_label;is_recurring;material;luggage_size;luggage_travel_style;bag_luggage_type;accessories_size;luggage_style;accessories_type;shoe_size;shoe_type;gendered;width;bedding_pattern;homeware_style;bed_bath_type;decor_type;home_decor_type;camera_type;camera_megapixels;electronic_type;cost;price_type;sku_type;weight_type;price_view;shipment_type;samples_title;links_title;links_purchased_separately;links_exist;format;books_music_type;author_artist;genre;style;necklace_length;jewelry_type;cover_type;recurring_profile;super_products_sku;super_attribute_code;super_attribute_option;super_attribute_price_corr;simples_skus;configurable_attributes
admin;base;Shoes;configurable;20;B9140760;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Catalog, Search;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;0;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;34;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;B9140760-13, B9140760-14, B9140760-15, B9140760-16, B9140760-17, B9140760-18, B9140760-19, B9140760-20, B9140760-21, B9140760-22, B9140760-23, B9140760-24, B9140760-25, B9140760-26;color,shoe_size;"""Blue"",""34,35,36,37,38""";;B9140760-13, B9140760-14, B9140760-15, B9140760-16, B9140760-17, B9140760-18, B9140760-19, B9140760-20, B9140760-21, B9140760-22, B9140760-23, B9140760-24, B9140760-25, B9140760-26;color,shoe_size
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-13;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-1.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;35;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-14;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-2.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;36;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-15;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-3.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;37;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-16;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-4.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;38;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-17;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-5.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;34;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-18;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-6.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;35;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-19;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-7.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;36;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-20;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-8.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;37;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-21;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-9.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;38;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-22;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-10.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;34;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-23;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-11.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;35;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-24;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-12.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;36;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-25;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-13.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;37;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
admin;base;Shoes;simple;20;B9140760-26;0;Shoes code 21-0120;;;;;;;giay-ma-21-0120;giay-ma-21-0120-14.html;;1 column;Product Info Column;;Use config;Use config;No;No;Blue;Enabled;Not Visible Individually;Taxable Goods;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;760.000;;;;;10;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;;;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;0;0;1;Giày m? 21-0120;0;simple;;;;;;;;;;;;;;38;;;M;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Can anyone tell me where i was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using MAGMI from your tags. Are you using the configurable items processor? Your SKUs have a common root that the configurable item processor can use so drop your simple skus columns and let the processor do the linking. You can also use it to force the visibility of associated simple products. But you probably want to put your configurable product after the simple products (I have separate files for my simple and configurable products).

You also have a column "product_type_id" which is "simple" for all rows. I don't know what that column is but is that right?

Finally, are you sure your csv file is in UTF-8 format, that can cause problems.

Good luck!

Comment: product_type_id column, i dunno but i think it's right 'cause i export a sample data then make my own base on that. it has 2 value: cafigurable, simple

Comment: about SKU, u mean i should remove that column and let Magmi generate it? it's kinda impossible, 'cause my company gave me a database with SKUs, basically SKU on magento must not different from original one

Comment: No, keep your SKUs as they are. The Magmi configurable items processor can see that there's a common root that it will use to link configurable and simple products. Btw, I forgot my usual advice in such cases: manually create a few products via the admin front end and export them. That will tell you for sure how the contents of each column should look.

Comment: i did. CSV above was created base on export data

Comment: also, even sample configurable product in back-end, but when i export, delete in db and import it. the sample configurable prd not linked to any associate prd =[[. that's why i have no idea where i was wrong

Comment: This is a good write up: https://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-configurable-item-processor/

Comment: somehow it only work with common SKU, Explicit Linking or other didnt work at all. not sure what to do now

Comment: You have a common SKU so can you not use that?

Comment: i dont have. after trying Explicit linking but not working, so i removed original SKU and replace it with common SKU. And it worked =]]

Comment: Your SKUs are of the form B9140760-13, B9140760-14, etc. The B9140760- is common. That's a perfect form for linking your simple products to a configurable product.

Comment: it actually look like this: 23210025C1140770, 23310025C1140770. but forget about SKU. my new problem is when i wanna use 2 attributes in the Configurable_attributes column (color, shoe_size), magmi return error "attribute_id" cannot be null" at the configurable product row then skipped import. i dunno where Magmi get "attribute_id" from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63995/discussion-between-pedroktfc-and-kami-x-oukarin).

Answer (score -1):

Took me a while to figure this out too. Simply put your simple products above the configurable ones in the same file. That way they are imported first then found and linked to the configurable.