# magmi configurable items are not grouped with their simple ones and images aren't imported

Tags: magento, import, magmi, configurable-product

Assistance appreciated.
I just did an import with magmi in Magento and all items are imported . However configurable items are not grouped with the simple ones!

This is my import CSV: <kbd>download [magmi.csv](http://awesomecowboy.com/magmitest.csv)</kbd>

Screen capture of import settings:

http://awesomecowboy.com/Capture.JPG

Comment: This discussion might help you.

Comment: My psychic powers aren't what they used to be, so here it is explicitly :o) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626989/import-configurable-product-not-link-to-associate-simple-product

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem by editing the attribute in magento so that simple is in  the list of product types the size attribute could be applied to.